# Zoom in MS Forms Chart does not behave as expected... or How to positional zoom a graph?

Tags: .net, forms, charts, zooming

I have a DataVisualization.Charting.Chart and i want to zoom a ChartArea with the mouse wheel. So far not too difficult. Now i want to do a positional zoom, i.e. the point under the mouse cursor is the center of the zoom. OK, i did some simple math and figured how calculate the new left/right end of my axis. If i set

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum
```

and `Maximum` to the new values, it works like a charm. If i, however, `zoom` to the values it does not work correctly. Here is my mouse wheel listener:

```
void Chart1MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var min = chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
        var max = chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
        var oldScale = max - min;

        var newScale = oldScale + (oldScale  * 0.001 * e.Delta);

        // calculate positional zoom
        var xAbs = chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
        var xRel = (xAbs - min)/(max - min);
        var min2 = min + oldScale*xRel - newScale*xRel;

        var max2 = min2 + newScale;

        // if i do that, it works perfectly
        //chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = min2;
        //chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = max2;

        // this does NOT work (at least not exactly)
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(min2, max2);
    }
```

What did i do wrong? How to use `Zoom` correctly?

The reason that i want to use the zoom is that this enables the scrolbar at the bottom of the chart.

Comment: I am facing the same issue..Did you find solution?

Comment: nop, we changed to a combination of VisiBlox Charts with the TA-Lib library. We evaluated quite a lot charting and indicator libraries, so let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(min2, max2-min2);`